# Windows 7 registry default value don't change?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I have a small problem which is I can't change the default value of files with extension .c to open with sublime text editor as default, although I can do that manually, I want to do it via .reg file, so I can do that with other extensions as well with only one reg file.

my tries:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.c\Shell\Open\Command]
"Default"="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

this creates another `Default` variable instead of replacing the default variable,
I tried this too

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.c\Shell\Open\Command]
"(Default)"="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

I thought maybe I need to write it the way it is in registry `(Default)`,
but that didn't work too, any solution to my problem?

Comment: Try using `@=` instead of `"Default"=` or `"(Default)"=`. You may also need to escape the backslashes like this: `C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\...`

Comment: @SamForbis Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have three mistakes, the first one is
that you need to escape backslashes, the second is that you
need to add the path symbol `%1` so that sublime editor gets
the path of the file as argument, the third one is you need
to write `@` if you want to change the default variable inside
a key, so you can do that like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.c\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe %1"
```

you can do that using cmd, but you need to open cmd
as an Administrator to have access to registry

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.c\Shell\Open\Command" /ve /d "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe %1" /f
```

**note:** don't escape backslashes in your command, because they are ordinary characters in this case
`/ve` to target `Default` variable, `/d` for data, and `/f` for forcing the overwriting